# Invoking an application from php script

Tags: php, android, matlab, tesseract

I am having problem in invoking tesseract from my below PHP script.

```
        $photo_upload_path = "./upload/";
        $photo_upload_path = $photo_upload_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        $processed_photo_output_path = "./output/processed_";
        $processed_photo_output_path = $processed_photo_output_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
        $processed_code_output_path = "./output/code_";
        $processed_code_output_path = $processed_code_output_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        if(copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $photo_upload_path)) {

            $command = "matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r \"Preprocess('$photo_upload_path','$processed_photo_output_path');exit\"";

          exec($command);

         $command = "tesseract.exe $processed_photo_output_path $processed_code_output_path";
          exec($command);
}
```

The above script is to process an image taken from android phone and extract characters using tesseract. When this code was executed,Matlab is getting invoked and I am getting a processed photo.But the tesseract is not running and I am not getting the extracted characters.But if i take a picture again from my phone,then tesseract runs immediately and gives extracted characters of previous processed photo but the previous processed photo will get replaced after some time.I dont want to take picture two times,instead on taking a picture I want both Matlab and tesseract to work.I hope you understood the question.

The tesseract is installed in `wamp/www` and the PHP script is in `wamp/www/`.
Output folder is in www folder. `Code.txt` is not created yet.

I have already searched other similar questions but found no solution.I am using PHP 5.4.12 and Apache 2.4.4.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. . Good luck!

Comment: On your question I'm not knowledgeable in tesseract but do you get any error messages or log messages?

Comment: @CAFEBABE Thank u for indenting.I dont get any error messages but the text file is not created.